# conflict using matlab-prettifier and LaTeX beamer

Tags: beamer, pdftex, listings, matlab

I was trying to use the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier?lang=en) package with the LaTeX [`beamer`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer?lang=en) package, and I noticed I was getting errors when trying to compile. Mainly I was getting an error when trying to use `matlab-prettifier` environment, within `beamer`'s `frame` environment.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\lstMakeShortInline[style=Matlab-editor]"

\begin{document}

\frame{
    "break" 
}

\end{document}
```

Trying to run this code sample gives me a "runaway argument error".

I should also say that the error is not limited to trying to insert the "double-quote" environment defined in the preamble, I've also tried using other `matlab-prettifier` environments, but haven't had any success...

Does anyone know of a workaround?